# What is the difference between 'let me know' and 'tell me'

Tags: meaning

There are two sentences like these.
1. let me introduce myself.
2. I'll tell you myself.

What is the difference between the two expressions in meaning?
Please, help me!

Comment: How do title and text fit? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Had you perhaps meant, "I'll tell you **about** myself"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there is no difference in meaning between 'let me know' and 'tell me'!

BUT in polite society there is a whole range of customary phrases and constructions that help people's interactions to run smoother. Many are very old, and are slowly fading into disuse, but it is never wrong to use them.

One is "Let me introduce myself (or someone else)", or "Allow me to introduce myself", better preceded by "Please", as "Please allow me to introduce myself". The assumption is that the introduction is an intrusion into the other person's life, and they are fully entitled to say no -- although in practice this never happens! In no circumstances could this request be considered as rude. The worst that could happen is that they might think you a little old-fashioned.

"I'll tell you myself" is a flat statement of intent, with no elements of courtesy involved. Depending on the context, in some situations this could conceivably be regarded as rude, although as it is an offer to impart information, it would usually be regarded favorably.

Answer (score 0):

These are two completely different sentences.

However, if you mean the difference between:

- Let me introduce myself.
- I'll tell you **about** myself.

Then, I would say that the former is used for more formal settings and the latter for more informal ones.

However, even then, I, personally, would probably still prefer the former over the latter.

The latter just feels a bit awkward unless used in a very specific context and in fact, I could not even find an example of it using Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=i%27ll%20tell%20you%20about%20myself&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=).

> PS -- As an aside, you could also say,
>
> - Allow me to introduce myself. (Even more formal.)

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know vs Please tell me.

There's no difference in meaning, but the former is a bit formal and the latter is more common and informal in everyday speech.

Let me introduce myself.

I tell myself.

The former is what you usually say when you make yourself known to somebody.

The latter has a different meaning.  If you tell yourself to do something, you advise, inform,or persuade yourself, not anybody else, to do something. For examples:

I kept myself telling to be quiet in the meeting.

I told myself there's nothing I could do to help him.

Furthermore, it can also mean that it's you who tell somebody. The reflexive pronoun "myself" has been used for emphasis.  For example:

A. Who told him that?

B. I did myself/I told myself.

Answer (score -1):

These answers misinterpret the question.  The question was not about "**Let me**", rather "**Let me know**" vs. "**Tell me**".  This is expressed best as follows:

"Let me know" doesn't usually mean the same thing as "Tell me."
"Let me know" usually refers to a piece of information about the **future**. The implication is that the other person doesn't know yet.

Examples:

1. "Let me know what you decide" (when you've made your decision).
         versus "Tell me what you decided" (expects an answer now)
2. "Let me know the time of the train" (accommodates a likely need for you
   to first find out).
         versus "Tell me the time of the train" (expects an answer now).
         Notably, a person faced with that question but not knowing the answer 
            might say, "I'll have to let you know (when I find out)."
3. "Let me know the results of the experiment" (when the experiment is complete).
         versus "Tell me the result of the experiment" (expects you know the result now)
4. "If he calls, let me know" (conditioned on a future event).

"**Tell me**" can refer to the present and past.

5. "Tell me about yourself" (Expectation is information now).
6. "Tell me what happened on the night of the burglary."

In contrast, "Let me know what happened..." would imply that the other person needed to go and
    find out what had happened.

Comment: Since you only read the title, not the rest of the question, your chutzpah in talking about how the other answers misinterpreted the question is pretty amusing. (One of them was even accepted by the asker themselves.)